# Memory allocation in c problem

Tags: c, memory, allocation

I'm nearing the end of an introductory book on c programming called "C programming in easy steps" by Mike McGrath. I think I'll have a lot more to learn after this book by the looks of things though. Anyways, I'm working with memory allocation and I wrote this demo program, but it errors closed when I try to run it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int i, *arr;

    arr = calloc(5, sizeof(int));
    if(arr!=NULL)
    {
        printf("Enter 5 integers, seperated by a space:");
        for(i=0; i<5; i++) scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        printf("Adding more space...\n");
        arr = realloc(8, sizeof(int));
        printf("Enter 3 more integers seperated by a space:");
        for(i=5; i<8; i++) scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        printf("Thanks.\nYour 8 entries were: ");
        for(i=0; i<8; i++) printf("%d, ", arr[i]);
        printf("\n");
        free(arr);
        return 0;
        }
    else {printf("!!! INSUFFICIENT MEMORY !!!\n"); return 1; }
}
```

Warning message:

```
|13|warning: passing argument 1 of 'realloc' makes pointer from integer without a cast|
c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\..\..\..\..\include\stdlib.h|365|note: expected 'void *' but argument is of type 'int'|
||=== Build finished: 0 errors, 1 warnings ===|
```

The resulting compilation asks for 5 integers and prints "Adding more space..." at which point the program terminates, instead of asking for the additional three integers and printing the input.

Any help would be nice. :) Thanks!

Comment: Please don't cram loop bodies onto the same line as the loop controls; it makes the code hard to read.  Also heed the warnings from your compiler - it is trying to help (and it currently knows more about C than you do).

Comment: You need to pass to `realloc` the address of the already in-use memory: `realloc(arr, 8 * sizeof (int));` Note that `realloc` can return `NULL`, if you assign the result value back to `arr`, you have no new memory and no old memory either. It's safer to use a temporary when reallocating.

Comment: Cool. Good to know. Thanks for the great advise. Sorry about the mess of code. That will be gaurenteed not to happen again. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not using `realloc` the way you should:

```
/* 8 is not valid here. You need to pass the previous pointer. */
arr = realloc(8, sizeof(int));
```

Try:

```
tmp = realloc(arr, 8 * sizeof(*arr));
if (NULL != tmp)
    arr = tmp;
```

As an aside, your program looks really crammed which makes it hard to read. Maybe leave an empty line once in a while ?

Comment: :) Yeah, I usually do leave more space, but I'm guilty of plagerism in this instance... Sorry Mike McGrath.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the pointer to the memory you want to resize:

```
tmp = realloc(arr, 8 * sizeof(int));
if (NULL != tmp)    
   arr = tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `realloc` should be the previously allocated pointer

Answer (score 0):

Look up how `realloc` works - you have to pass it the original pointer:

```
int * tmp = realloc(arr, 8 * sizeof(int));
if (tmp)
{
  arr = tmp;
}
else // Error!
```

Comment: I guess I know the way to explain

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `realloc` is wrong.

```
    // ptr: Pointer to a memory block previously allocated with malloc, calloc or
    // realloc to be reallocated.
    void * realloc ( void * ptr, size_t size );
```

You should use `realloc(arr, 8 * sizeof(int));`

Answer (score -1):

At fist You gotta learn the the way to use realloc.
The reason for  the 1st warning your seeing on your screen

```
passing argument 1 of 'realloc' makes pointer from integer without a cast
 int i, *arr;          
 arr = calloc(5, sizeof(int)); \\ Not the right way 
 arr = (int *) calloc (5,sizeof(int)); \\ makes sense
```

You have to type cast the pointer returned by The calloc before it is being assigned.Thats why you got the warning without a cast.
Note

```
char *arr ; arr = (char *) realloc (5,sizeof(char))
double *char: arr =(double *) realloc (5,sizeof(double))
```

I guess you got the point.Typecast it into the type of the pointer your going to assign. because the calloc returns void pointer and you have to type cast into the data type you want before you use it

and As far to my Knowledge

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++) scanf("%d", &arr[i]);  \\ this is not the way to use pointers
this would be mostly used in arrays !
```

This is the way to use pointers

```
      *(arr+1) or *(arr+any_variable) \\
```

and remember as your defining arr as integer pointer it increments its address by 2

```
example arr pointing to 3000 memory location after *(arr+1)
points to 3002 location and if arr pointer is ,char *arr, then
arr pointing to 3000 then *(arr +1 ) now it will point to 3001 location
same for double by 8 and for float 4 .
```

1 does not mean by 1 it means increment it by the size of the pointer pointing to.
well I never noticed this kind of syntax for pointers

```
     &arr[i]
```

If that is also the way to use pointers then I'm glad to accept it I learned the other way to access pointers

```
   but think of using these *(arr+i) mostly
```

well you can also use

```
 (int *) calloc(5, sizeof(int))
 \\ the number of bytes allocated by it is 5 * sizeof(int) = 5*2 =10
```

Thanks.

and please go through these 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/calloc/ and these site is really really promsising site for beginners I hope you enjoy and any doubts we are here to help you

Comment: While casting is necessary in C++, it is not preferred in C. A `void *` can be assigned to another pointer type; conversion will happen implicitly. Adding the cast to silence compiler warnings is a false fix as it usually indicates a missing `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: Notice the warning was about "argument" not "assignment operand."

Comment: oopz sorry didnt notice it well i use to get that warnings when i work on turbo c anyways !